# Access value based on array key

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax call which returns a JSON response and i'm loading the response using an array

```
var results = { 
    "appointmentrequired": {"name": "Appointment Required?"},
};

success: function(data) {
    $.each(results, function(key, value) {
        // show results from `data` here
    });
}
```

But I'm not sure how to access the results inside the array loop.

I've tried

```
console.log(data[key]);
console.log(data.key);
```

But both return `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `console.log()` both `key` and `value` you should be able to see what's being provided to the function arguments.

As such, either `data[key].name` or `value.name` is what you need.

```js
// mock AJAX response data
var data = {
  "appointmentrequired": {
    "name": "Appointment Required?"
  },
};

// in AJAX response handler
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  console.log('key:', key)
  console.log('value:', value);

  console.log('Name from key:', data[key].name);
  console.log('Name from value:', value.name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i'm trying to retrieve the value from `data` in my ajax request

Comment: Ok, so change `results` to `data`. I did it this way so it worked in the snippet given the example in your question

Comment: so, that would mean i need to use `data[key]` to retrieve the value from the ajax request with the key in `results`?

Comment: In which case you've either got a typo somewhere or the format of the response is not what you expect it to be. Given the data structure you provide in the question this works fine, as can be seen in the snippet. If it doesn't work for you please edit the question to give a more accurate example of your code, and the response.

Comment: if I `console.log(data["appointmentrequired"]);` i get undefined. My JSON response looks like `{"appointmentrequired":"yes"}`

Comment: `My JSON response looks like {"appointmentrequired":"yes"}` That cannot be the case otherwise the code would work.

Comment: ok, to ensure there are no spelling mistakes etc i've updated the response of `data` to `{"test":"yes"}` then i run `console.log( data["test"] );` which returns `undefined`

Comment: Then again, the response simply cannot be what you expect it to be. You need to debug exactly what the response is when received in JS and go from there.

Comment: just reaslied, I've missed out `dataType: "json",`

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over `data` returned from the api, not `results`:

```
success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
       console.log(key, value) // appointmentrequired {name: "Appointment Required?"}
    });
}
```

Comment: i want to iterate over the results array to show all the information in there, and then find whether data returns a value - if it does, display it, if not just display "-"

Comment: @charlie There is no Array shown in your `results` object

Answer (score -1):

`$.each` run on arrays

You want to explore `let keysArr = Object.keys(data)`

Comment: From jQuery docs: "jQuery.each( array, callback ): A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both **objects** and arrays."